# N channel MOSFET to drive 9-12V device with micro controller

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet

Would this MOSFET would fine for driving things like a 9-12V DC motor?

Datasheet: http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/1560173.pdf

Comment: How much current does this motor consume? You should account for start current as well as stall current.

Comment: Last time I measured the current I think it was about 200mA

Answer (score 1):

Direct gate drive by the controller probably won't work well, even if the controller has nominally 5 volt outputs, and if it has 3.3 volt outputs will definitely not work.

If you look at the second page of the data sheet, you'll see Vgs(th), the voltage necessary to turn on the FET, of 2 to 4 volts. Problem is, if you look closely you'll see that "on" means 250 uA, which is not likely a useful current to drive a motor with.

So you'll need some sort of level shifter between the controller and the FET. In many ways the easiest approach is to use a gate driver IC. I personally favor the Maxim 4426/4427 chips, but that's just habit. Go to any supplier and search on "gate driver".

If you have some NPN transistors handy, you can make something like

[image: schematic]

will do. Don't forget the diode, which should have the same current rating (or more) as the motor. If you don't include it, you risk killing the FET when you turn off the motor.